# Setting Alpha Slider and Feature Count ON by default using QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, layers, tools

In QGIS 3.4, I would like to automatize and uniformize the appearance of each layer.

I would like that each new layer is created:

- with the alpha slider activated

[image: Alpha Slider]

- with Feature count activated

[image: Layer Entity Count]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following in the **Python Console** which:

- Enables the **feature count** setting for vector-type layers
- Enables the transparency slider for any layer

These are applied whenever a layer is added:

```
def enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider(layers):
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    layer = layers[0]
    # Enable feature count for vector-type layers
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        myLayerNode = root.findLayer(layer.id())
        myLayerNode.setCustomProperty("showFeatureCount", True)
    # Enable transparency slider
    if layer.customProperty("embeddedWidgets/count") != 1 or layer.customProperty("embeddedWidgets/0/id") != u'transparency':
        layer.setCustomProperty("embeddedWidgets/count", 1)
        layer.setCustomProperty("embeddedWidgets/0/id", "transparency")
    # Refresh legend symbology
    iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())

# Connect "legendLayersAdded" event to "enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider" function
QgsProject.instance().legendLayersAdded.connect(enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider)
```

To disconnect the function, use:

```
QgsProject.instance().legendLayersAdded.disconnect(enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider)
```

---

[image: enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider]

Comment: Works directly for me. Thanks a lot for your detailed answer ! I am just beginning with pyScript, it helped a lot.

Comment: What do you use to create the animated picture you add in your answer ?

Comment: @kFly - Most welcome! Glad it helped :). I used [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/).

Comment: Do you how I can run your script automatically when opening a new project ( [ QGIS3]? I thought in was in *startup.py* but I did not manage to make it work for the moment.

Comment: @kFly - Did you put the script in `C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\startup.py`? When you and you run QGIS, you might receive errors such as `module x is not defined` etc. It just means you need to import these at the beginning of the script (i.e. import module x).

Comment: On linux the directory should be: `/$HOME/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python`     I do not get any error message. My `startup.py` is : `## Scripts  Python GIS     //
import enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider    #  //
enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider.run()`

Comment: @kFly - You don't run the function manually, you connect it to a signal which is emitted whenever a layer is added to QGIS which is what this line does: `QgsProject.instance().legendLayersAdded.connect(enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider)`

Comment: I replaced my last line `enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider.run()` with yours, but the script does not activate when adding a new layer. I got this message from qgis log : `Warning: QObject::connect: signal not found in QgisAppInterface`. Not sure if it is connected.

Comment: @kFly - I tested the script as a startup. I had to include the lines `from qgis.core import QgsMapLayer, QgsProject` and `from qgis.utils import iface` at the beginning. After QGIS has loaded, it works. Did you put it in the same directory called "Python" or did you put it inside this directory? I'm not a linux user so not sure if this is the correct path or not. If it is correct then perhaps the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: Many thanks Joseph. Script is still not active at startup. I wrote a separate subject, to be able to format the text:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330967/qigs-running-a-script-when-opening-any-project