# Running PyQGIS script when opening any project in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

This question is a follow-up of this topic:
[Setting Alpha Slider and Feature Count ON by default using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329919/qgis-3-4-setting-alpha-slider-and-feature-count-on-by-default/329984?noredirect=1#comment539750_329984)

I am trying to run this script for each new project I open.

But I am failing of making it active.

From my knowledge of QGIS, a script called `startup.py` should be created.

In QGIS 3, this script is there

[Linux] `/$HOME/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python`

[Windows] `C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python`\startup.py

(You can check this directory under : Settings > User Profile > Open Active Profile Directory)

My `startup.py` script is :

```
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.utils import iface
import enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider    #Activation sub

QgsProject.instance().legendLayersAdded.connect(enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider)
```

The routine enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider is stored in the same directory as startup.py and as the following content:

```
def enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider(layers):
# By Joseph (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329919/qgis-3-4-setting-alpha-slider-and-feature-count-on-by-default/329984#329984)
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    layer = layers[0]
    # Enable feature count for vector-type layers
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        myLayerNode = root.findLayer(layer.id())
        myLayerNode.setCustomProperty("showFeatureCount", True)
    # Enable transparency slider
    if layer.customProperty("embeddedWidgets/count") != 1 or layer.customProperty("embeddedWidgets/0/id") != u'transparency':
        layer.setCustomProperty("embeddedWidgets/count", 1)
        layer.setCustomProperty("embeddedWidgets/0/id", "transparency")
    # Refresh legend symbology
    iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())

# Connect "legendLayersAdded" event to "enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider" function
QgsProject.instance().legendLayersAdded.connect(enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider)
```

I have got no message from qgis windows.
When running manually startup.py from the console I have got the following error message:

> *QgsProject.instance().legendLayersAdded.connect(enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider)
>   NameError: name 'QgsProject' is not defined*

What am I missing and how do I correct it?

Comment: you need import QgsProject `from qgis.core import QgsProject`

Comment: your question's title is a bit misleading since you know how to start a script using _startup.py_ ...

Comment: @FranRaga: already done at line 2, in startup.py.

Answer (score 2):

Your Windows path is incorrect, it should be:

```
C:/Users/You/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/startup.py
```

This would explain why you are not receiving any error messages because you should be. If you have a small number of simple functions, it might be better to store them all in your *startup.py* so you can just load this single file:

```
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayer, QgsProject
from qgis.utils import iface

def enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider(layers):
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    layer = layers[0]
    # Enable feature count for vector-type layers
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        myLayerNode = root.findLayer(layer.id())
        myLayerNode.setCustomProperty("showFeatureCount", True)
    # Enable transparency slider
    if layer.customProperty("embeddedWidgets/count") != 1 or layer.customProperty("embeddedWidgets/0/id") != u'transparency':
        layer.setCustomProperty("embeddedWidgets/count", 1)
        layer.setCustomProperty("embeddedWidgets/0/id", "transparency")
    # Refresh legend symbology
    iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())

QgsProject.instance().legendLayersAdded.connect(enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider)
```

---

However, if you want to store this function in a separate file in the same directory as *startup.py* and load it via this startup file, then add the following to *startup.py*:

```
import sys, os
from qgis.utils import iface
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

import enableFeatCountAndAlphaSlider
```

Comment: I am running QGIS on a Linux OS. According to this qgis doc, the directory is to be  correct (QGIS3.4?): https://qgis.org/test/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-python-code-when-qgis-starts. However I suspect the startup.py is not read because I dont see any message in terminal when I launch qgis. I don't know how to check or force the reading ? This question seems related but has no solution yet: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296504/startup-py-in-qgis-not-executed

Comment: @kFly - So you tested this path on Linux :`/$HOME/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/startup.py`?

Comment: Yes. I a also put all the commands in `startup.py`. I also tryed with a buggy script. Script is not active in a new project, and no error/message is shown in the lauching console.

Comment: @kFly - Perhaps you should [ask a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) concerning the correct path for a Linux system for startup scripts.

Comment: @kFly - Have you tried the method posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318222/qgis-3-startup-script-is-not-executed) where you could enter `QStandardPaths.locateAll( QStandardPaths.AppDataLocation, "startup.py" )` into the Python Console and if it returns a path then it is correct, if it returns an empty list then the path is incorrect.